# Django QuerySet Filter by week_day returning nothing

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-queryset

I am currently trying to filter my QuerySet results by the day of the week in Django 2.0.
I can't for the life of me get the django [week_day](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#week-day) filter `datetime__week_day` to return any results.

**Model**

```
class Session(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return str.join(', ', (str(self.game.name), str(self.datetime_created), str(self.start)))

    game = models.ForeignKey(
        'Game',
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )

    datetime_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)
    start = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True,)
    end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True,)
    competitive = models.BooleanField(default=False,)
```

**Filtering**

```
filtered_sessions = Session.objects.filter(
    start__week_day=2,
).exclude(start__isnull=True)
```

I currently have an entry in the sessions table (MySQL backend) which contains the datetime `2018-04-30 23:51:42.000000`, so I would expect this QuerySet to contain that 'Session' as it occurs on a Monday.

Referring back to the documentation, The week goes from Sunday(1) to Saturday(7).
I have `USE_TZ` in my settings, `TIME_ZONE='UTC'`.
Irrespective of these settings, I have also tried replacing the `start__week_day=2` with values from 0-8 (inclusive, just in case)

My question is this: Why is what I am trying is not returning any results?

Please let me know if I've left out something that would help answer my query.
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I have since attempted to run a direct query in the database (`SELECT * FROM mysite_session WHERE DAYOFWEEK('start') IN (0-8);`)
No result in the database.

Comment: Do you have `USE_TZ = True` in your settings, and what timezone are you using? The most likely issue is that when Django converts into your local timezone that timestamp ends up being on the Tuesday.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes I do have that, and it's using `UTC`, but regardless I have tried all the way from 1-7 in the week-day filter but no luck.

Comment: he said that above, django 2.0

Comment: May be you need to cast it into Date first and need to get week day, like below, please check once. `start__date__week_day=2`

Comment: No luck unfortunately, same result (nothing returned)

Comment: I don't think it should matter, but `exclude(start__isnull=True)` is redundant - can you try removing that?

Comment: @solarissmoke I have that there as start time is not necessarily known when a session is created. Removing it doesn't fix the issue, just checked

Comment: DEBUG trick: you have data in your db, so query from [1-7] or [0-8] to see which number of the day will return values.

Comment: If you are referring to manually modifying the values in the filter, I have tried that (see question: `I have also tried replacing the start__week_day=2 with values from 0-8 (inclusive, just in case) `)

Comment: @JamesM. Check this RAW, if it working may be you need to go for RAW. `SELECT DAYOFWEEK(start), start FROM sessions WHERE DAYOFWEEK(start) = '2';` OR try this `Session.objects.filter(start__dow=2)`

Comment: @AnupYadav The sql (When run in the database) claims to have a syntax error.
The filter says 'Unsupported lookup 'dow' for DatTimeField or join on the field not permitted'.

Comment: @JamesM. Yes, I saw later its mysql, please check this `SELECT DAYOFWEEK(start), start FROM sessions WHERE DAYOFWEEK(start) = '2';` AND for same using Django use `Session.objects.filter(start__dow=2)`

Comment: @AnupYadav The sql does return the correct result!
The django alternative is not working as per the previous result

Comment: Ok, but may be you need to use the same one RAW one. Seems there is issue with mysql and Django. Because its working for me with Postgresql

Comment: @JamesM. I've added that as an answer, please accept the answer if found useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours more of research and testing, it turns out that my issue was indeed due to `USE_TZ`, but not directly.

The problem was that I didn't import my timezones correctly into my MySQL database.
Firstly, I didn't have the required tables (which I found [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.6/scripts/mysql_system_tables.sql) on lines 60-72)
Secondly, I didn't correctly set up my timezones.
I ran `mysql_tz_info_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root`
where I should've ran
`mysql_tz_info_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo/ | mysql -u root mysql`

After correctly running that command and ensuring that I did indeed have the tables in my database, I was able to execute the Django Filter successfully.

Thank you to everyone who helped, as I wouldn't have discovered the issue without your input!

Comment: There is a correction in the command on Ubuntu 16.04 its : mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo/ | mysql -u root -p mysql

Comment: After looking for 3 hours found your solution. This worked. Thanks mate.